# How to access inner virtual DOM elements on onChange call from a parent component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following example:

```
const ChildComponent = ({funcFromParent}) => {

  const funcFromChild = (e) => {
    funcFromParent(e)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>ChildComponent</h1>

      <div className="myCoolDiv" onChange={funcFromChild}>
        <div className="myCoolDivTwo">
          <input type="text" className="myCoolInput"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

So, when I get the call from the `funcFromParent` back to my `ParentComponent`, how am I supposed to access the inner DOM properties? I mean, I know there's a virtual DOM in React and all that, but is there any standardize/practical way that isn't considered a bad practice to access, say, `myCoolInput`?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the DOM?

Comment: @OriDrori for example grab the event of the input and extract it's properties, such as name, value. There's many cases I can use it, but of course I'm not gonna mutate the DOM tree etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `currentTarget` attribute of the event is the actual DOM subtree of the element on to which the event handler is set. You can access the any element in the subtree using standard DOM methods. For example, to get the input:

```js
const ChildComponent = ({funcFromParent}) => {
  const funcFromChild = (e) => {
    funcFromParent(e.currentTarget)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ChildComponent</h1>

      <div className="myCoolDiv" onChange={funcFromChild}>
        <div className="myCoolDivTwo">
          <input type="text" className="myCoolInput"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const func = currentTarget => {
    const input = currentTarget.querySelector('input')
    console.log(input && input.value)
  }
  
  return <ChildComponent funcFromParent={func} />
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentComponent />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

However, passing the actual DOM subtree to the parent breaks the component's encapsulation. It's better to set the event handler on the input, and pass just the value:

```js
const ChildComponent = ({funcFromParent}) => {
  const funcFromChild = e => {
    funcFromParent(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ChildComponent</h1>

      <div className="myCoolDiv" onChange={funcFromChild}>
        <div className="myCoolDivTwo">
          <input type="text" className="myCoolInput"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const func = value => {
    console.log(value)
  }
  
  return <ChildComponent funcFromParent={func} />
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentComponent />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ori, but can you please elaborate on the encapsulation part, I mean sure, I won't use the `querySelector`, because it's not going to be reliable due the state changes may occur(right?), but saying that passing `e.target.value` from one component to another... how does it really different from passing a value? After all, this(the `e.target.value`) is the value. So passing the `input` itself and extracting the `name` and `value`, for example and passing it to the parent... what harm can it make, or what difference will be if I'll just pass them separately as a custom object?

Comment: Passing the value means that the interface between parent and child is loose - the parent passes a function, and expect a value when the function is called. Using the child's DOM structure in the parent is coupling them tightly - ie whenever you'll change the child, you'll need to changed the parent's code as well. If for example, you'll decide to change the child's input to textarea, you'll need to do the same thing to the parent. If this is not the only parent in which the child is used, you'll have to refactor all of them. However, this parent's might have other parents, and so on.

Comment: Oh, I see now what you meant. It's true, but if I chose to go this way(let's just say I'm aware of that this will never change etc), what I may use then to access the inner elements of the `myCoolDiv`, like the `input`? As I see it, the `querySelector` is not reliable in this situation as I mentioned before. Any ideas, maybe? In any case, I appreciate your help

Comment: The querySelector is reliable, as long as you you use it immediately in a synchronous way. You can use other DOM methods/properties as well. As long as you don't store the currentTarget, and try to access it later you'll be fine. However, the coupling will bite you in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useRef` hook like this:

```
const inputRef = useRef();

return (
    <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
);
```

Now, a reference to the input is accessible through `inputRef.current` - you can pass it up the tree.

More information can be found [here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Comment: But I don't want to access one element and hard code it like that... I want to be able to access any element inside that tree.